# What determines the name of a partial class created by a .razor file in a Blazor project?

Tags: blazor

I'm teaching myself to write web apps with Blazor.

I see that when I create a new .razor file, Visual Studio creates a partial class with the same name as the name of the .razor file.

However, looking at my code, the only place I see the name of the partial class is in the name of the file (unless I create a code-behind file).  Does the name of the file determine the name of the class, or is there some other place that the name of the class is specified?

Comment: The name of the file itself.

Comment: You mean the ".g.cs" file?

Comment: for each razor file, it creates a path for the generated class (the “.g.cs” file)

Comment: If I then change the name of the file, does that change the name of the generated class?